# Android Device Total Internal Storage

Tags: android

I'm trying to find out the total storage space a device has.
I've tried:

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); 
statFs.getTotalBytes();
statFs.getBlockCountLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
```

and both methods return the same number, which is **~2GB**, when I know that my device has **16GB** total storage space (accessible and inaccessible).

How can I get the real storage size? Not only available or free space, every last scrap of a byte a device has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need is this:

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
```

because `getRootDirectory();` gets you the "system" partition holding the core Android OS.

Then, the other method will get you the total storage space...

Comment: Following your advice I used this, and got 12 GB ( which is a big improvement ;) ), which I guess is the "free use" partition, since its not 16 GB.. Do you suppose I should sum both partitions to get the total storage space? or is there a better way?

Comment: I was just reading on that, and I assume that Android methods do not allow you to get the "real" number because some amount of memory is "in the use". Also, there is [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-s/315804-guide-android-memory-how-deal-low-memory-warnings.html) article, where were explained 3 types of memory in Android, check it out... I guess you could sum both partitions, but I do not know if there is a way to get the "real" number though...